# Python - Checking lists against lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I am working on a script that will scrape a page and find the names of adoptable dogs. I am able to scrape and append the names to a list. But, I am having trouble having the code run continuously and append new names to a new list and remove them from the old list. Wondering if someone could help me work through this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
from twilio.rest import Client

url = 'http://petharbor.com/results.asp?searchtype=ADOPT&start=3%20&friends=1&samaritans=1&nosuccess=0&rows=25&imght=200&imgres=thumb&tWidth=200&view=sysadm.v_chmp&bgcolor=b7b7b7&text=ffffff&link=ffffff&alink=4400ff&vlink=ffffff&fontface=arial&fontsize=12&col_hdr_bg=000066&col_hdr_fg=ffffff&SBG=000066&zip=61802&miles=10&shelterlist=%27CHMP%27&atype=&where=type_DOG&PAGE=1'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

account_sid = ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
auth_token = ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

names = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("My name is(.*)"))

def check():
    old = []
    new = []
    newest = []

    for name in names:
        name = name.title()
        if name not in old:
            old.append(name[11:-2])
            if name in old:
                continue

    for name in names:
        name = name.title()
        if name in old:
            continue
        if name not in new and name not in old:
            new.append(name[11:-2])
        if name not in new and name in old:
            new.append(name[11:-2])
            old.remove(name)
        if name in new and name in old:
            old.remove(name)
            new.remove(name)

    for name in names:
        name = name.title()
        if name in old or name in new:
            continue
        if name not in old and name not in new:
            newest.append(name[11:-2])

    num_old = len(old)
    num_new = len(new)
    num_newest = len(newest)

    print("Old List: " + str(old))
    print("Number of dogs in the old list: " + str(num_old))
    print("New List: " + str(new))
    print("Number of new dogs: " + str(num_new))
    print("Newest List: " + str(newest))
    print("Number of newest dogs: " + str(num_newest))

    #client.api.account.messages.create(to = "+XXXXXXXXXX",
                                        #from_= "+XXXXXXXXXX",
                                        #body = "Here are some new dogs:" + str(new))

    #client.api.account.messages.create(to="+XXXXXXXXXX",
                                       #from_="+XXXXXXXXXX",
                                       #body=("There are " + str(num_newest) + " new puppies"), media_url = 'http://petharbor.com/results.asp?searchtype=ADOPT&start=3%20&friends=1&samaritans=1&nosuccess=0&rows=25&imght=200&imgres=thumb&tWidth=200&view=sysadm.v_chmp&bgcolor=b7b7b7&text=ffffff&link=ffffff&alink=4400ff&vlink=ffffff&fontface=arial&fontsize=12&col_hdr_bg=000066&col_hdr_fg=ffffff&SBG=000066&zip=61802&miles=10&shelterlist=%27CHMP%27&atype=&where=type_DOG&PAGE=1')

    #client.api.account.messages.create(to = "+XXXXXXXXXX",
                                        #from_= "+XXXXXXXXXX",
                                        #body = "Here are some new names:" + str(newest))


while True:
    check()
    time.sleep(20)
```

This is the current output:

```
Old List: ['Pretty', 'Celia', 'Khloe', 'Duke', 'Evangeline', 'Thelma', 'Clara', 'Carly', 'Camille', 'Maxine', 'Jupiter', 'Pixie', 'Smiley', 'Mia', 'Pogo', 'Rosco', 'Clark', 'Ellie', 'Marcy', 'Jimmy', 'Willie', 'Layla']
Number of dogs in the old list: 22
New List: ['Pretty', 'Celia', 'Khloe', 'Duke', 'Evangeline', 'Thelma', 'Clara', 'Carly', 'Camille', 'Maxine', 'Jupiter', 'Pixie', 'Smiley', 'Mia', 'Pogo', 'Rosco', 'Clark', 'Ellie', 'Marcy', 'Jimmy', 'Willie', 'Layla']
Number of new dogs: 22
```

I am trying to get it to update to something like:

```
Old List: ['Pretty', 'Celia', 'Khloe', 'Duke', 'Evangeline', 'Thelma', 'Clara', 'Carly', 'Camille', 'Maxine', 'Jupiter', 'Pixie', 'Smiley', 'Mia', 'Pogo', 'Rosco', 'Clark', 'Ellie', 'Marcy', 'Jimmy', 'Willie', 'Layla']
Number of dogs in the old list: 22
New List: ['Max', 'Charlie']
Number of new dogs: 2
```

I will try to restate what I am trying to do:

1. Run script to scrape names from website and store in list ('old').
2. Re-check website and collect names
3. If names are duplicate do not append them to list.
4. If names are not duplicates, append to a list ('new')
5. Continue running and move names to old list and remove from new list if there are new, non-duplicate, names.

Comment: Hi, so I'm not sure I exactly understand what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're trying to reuse the `old` and `new` list, which you could do, but you'd need to place them outside the `check` function. Imagine the `;` is a new line: `old = list(); new = list(); def check():; # your code`. You're unable to reuse the lists as they are now, because they get redefined as empty lists every time `check()` is called.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, let me see if I can reword it. I'd like the function to run every 30 minutes. I am trying to have it check the names on the page and in the end update upon new names. I'd like it to on the first run append the names to the old list and during the next function to cross-check the names against the old list and if there are names that do not match to append them to a new list. And, if possible, do this with a newest list once it has been running.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want. Do you just want an updated list of names with no duplicates every time you run the function?

Comment: Yea, I still don't understand. I tried to provide an answer that would probably do what you're asking if the rest of your code worked, but I don't understand what you're doing in all these for loops.

Comment: in situations like these, please provide some sample data, and the expected output.

Comment: Basically to create an updated list with no duplicates.  I tried using to loops to add or remove a name whether if it is present. I'd like to be able to look at a list ("new") and know these are not duplicates in the old list.

Comment: Have you looked into using `set` instead of list. It might make your life easier because then you can do `intersection` `difference` pretty easily